# Change Lightbox 2 animation speed

Tags: jquery, animation, lightbox, lightbox2

[Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) is a wonderful jQuery extension. It does the job on displaying images well, but the animations are unbelivably slow, literally!

The user gets annoyed very quickly and leaves. I've seen Lightbox alternatives even slower, folding out the popup progressively. I can't figure out who would want such a thing.

**Question**

How can I change the speed of the animations of Lightbox 2, preferably without alternating the original code, i.e. using properties?

Comment: It looks like under the variable LightboxOptions on line 14, you can edit some of the animations. Other then that I am not sure if you'll be able to rig the animations separate without a lot of work, at that point you might as well just build your own light box. Why can't you edit the original code?

Comment: I don't want to change the code because then I would have to do this every time I update Lightbox. Also, this is not best-practice at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can speed up the fade using `fadeDuration` and resize speed using `resizeDuration` but this will mean editing them in the original script.

Unfortunately as the script is self instantiating so the only way to change the options is to change the script itself

[Example of a faster fade in and resize](http://jsfiddle.net/fbv6ae28/3/)

A good alternative to lightbox is FancyBox 2 which allows you to instantiate it yourself and target particular links allowing for more control over the animations for each set of links

[Here is a link to it's api](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: That's the best compromise I think I can get. I'll also look at fancyBox. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox 2 seems to support modifying many options including animation speeds. Check here the available options http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Example:

```
<script>
    lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 20,
      'fadeDuration': 20,
      'imageFadeDuration': 30,
      'wrapAround': false,
    })
</script>
```